# Can't find favicon source in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html

I'm viewing [this page](http://www.molecularassembler.com/Nanofactory/Challenges.htm) and it has a favicon that I can't find the URL of in the source code or in the network requests tab when loading the page. How do I find this image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://molecularassembler.com/favicon.ico

Websites just need to have **"favicon.ico"** in their root, and modern browsers will automatically fetch this icon file.

Here is an article with many references:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon